# IBM Worklight Version 6.1.0 with embedded WL Development Server on Win 7, consistent Android build error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

On Windows 7, have installed: 
1) Eclipse Standard 4.3.1 64 bit edition, 
2) 64 bit JRE deployed in Eclipse folder, 
3) IBM Worklight Studio version 6.1.0 from Eclipse Marketplace, and finally 
4) ADT deployed from Eclipse Marketplace.

Creating simple default Hybrid Hello World app.
I do a "Run As Android Application" and get the error: "The project was not built since the build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for the java.lang.Object.

Details attached in screen captures. Odd since I am including the JRE as is evident in the Build Path preferences shown in the attached screen captures below.

Have tried this on two different clean computers and get the same error.

[image: Eclipse Project screen shot]
[image: Syntax errors in generated Java file]
[image: Compile errors]
[image: Classpath variables]
[image: Installed JREs]

Comment: What android SDKs do you have installed?   Are they up to date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open android sdk manager and install android api level 18 you're missing and restart your IDE

Comment: I am happy I've helped you :) Enjoy your coding :)